# How to run a linear regression with residual variances estimated by a GARCH model?

Tags: python

My question is twofold. Given that I have a linear equation (market equation) to predict a time series (stock returns), a) how can I adjust the error variance using a GARCH-model given that heteroskedasticity is present b) how would I code this in python?

Let me be more clear. I try to replicate an event study on stock returns. The paper specified a mean-equation (market model) and GARCH, EGARCH, TGARCH for estimated residual variance.

The model to predict stock returns is `R(j,t)=alpha(j)+beta(j)*R(m,t)+e(j,t)` (see photo).
`e(j,t)` follows `N(0,h(j,t))`, where `h(j,t)` needs to be estimated with some type of GARCH-Model. ( see photo).

I am assuming that the idea is to:

a) Regress the GARCH model on the time series (stock returns)

b) run the linear regression (mean-equation) conditional with residuals following 0 mean and the GARCH-estimated variance.

- Is my that interpretation right?
- How would I code this in python?

Any help, references or tips would be highly appreciated. 
(The study I try to replicated is from the paper "The impact of the SARS outbreak on Taiwanese hotel stock performance: An event-study approach")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from arch import arch_model


am = arch_model(Y, X, mean='LS')
res = am.fit()
```

The code `am = arch_model(Y, X, mean='LS')` automatically adds constant to '`X`' and use GARCH(1,1) for volatility estimation, which is what you wanted